# Revert Local Codebase to a particular Heroku release

Tags: git, heroku, bitbucket

I inherited a codebase and after working on the project I realized the previous developer didn't push the code to Bitbucket hence my local version is wrong.
So I want to clone a particular release from Heroku.

How can i do this

Comment: How are you deploying to Heroku? Via `git push`, GitHub integration, or something else? And are you using Docker onHeroku?

Comment: Yes via git push and Docker is not is use

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please take a careful look at your existing repository to see if the code is actually there. It might be in a different branch, for example. You should be able to see which commit hash has been used for the most recent commit with [`heroku releases`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases#listing-release-history) or looking at its "Activity" tab in the web panel.

Assuming the commit is actually missing, and since your app is deployed via `git push`¹, you should be able to fetch from Heroku (assuming your remote is named `heroku`):

```
git fetch heroku
```

After this you should be able to create a new local branch from that commit, e.g. via

```
git branch new-branch heroku/master
```

Please [don't make a habit of this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical "origin" repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub.

---

¹GitHub deployment doesn't update Heroku's Git repository. If you deploy via GitHub or with Docker you won't be able to get the latest code using `git fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a way to do this without performing any destructive actions on your app.

First, make sure you have a git remote in place for your Heroku app locally. You can do so by running `heroku git:remote -a your-app-name` from the root directory of your local app. (Confirm this running `cat .gitconfig`.)

Note: It is important to keep in mind that Heroku highly discourages its users from relying on the git repository that Heroku itself hosts for your app. This is intended to be used for code deployment only.

That said, it is possible to `git pull` from your app on Heroku. Not knowing your situation fully, it's hard to know exactly which commands to give you. That said, If `git pull heroku master` results in a conflict, you might consider forcing a `git pull` to a local branch instead. This way the master branch is kept in tact while you are still able to get a copy of the code running on Heroku.

Once you have the code that is currently running on Heroku, run `heroku releases -a your-app-name` to get a list of the most recent releases for your app. Find the one you are interested in and make a note of the SHA hash. This is the git commit you're looking for.

Once you have this, you can simply use `git reset --hard abcdef` (where `abcdef` is the SHA you retrieved from the release you're interested in).

Now your local repository is rolled back to the specific commit you were looking for.